# Overriding the default date format validation on the AccountModel in MVC4 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, azure, simplemembership

I have created a windows form based application and am using the simple membership AccountModel. On the registration form I am having problems with the date format when the application is uploaded to azure.

Locally I am able to enter the format "31/10/2013" but on the azure hosted application I must enter it in the format "10/31/2013". How can I override the validation so that it allows the use of DD/MM/YYYY format

My register model is as follows:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Forename")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "DOB")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Secret Answer")]
    public string SecretAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

I tried applying a dateformat to the DOB property as above but on azure it is still validating against MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 3):

The FormatAttribute of the Mvc Controls Toolkit enables the developer to define the format to be used in the representation of a property on the client side, as shown in the example below :-

```
    Format(Prefix="Date of birth is: ", ClientFormat = "d", NullDisplayText="No date of birth available")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

This way, the strings can be globalized as explained here.

```
Below the list of all supported date format:
Format  Meaning     "en-US"
f   Long Date, Short Time   dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
F   Long Date, Long Time    dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
G   Short Date, Long Time   M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
t   Short Time  h:mm tt
T   Long Time   h:mm:ss tt
d   Short Date  M/d/yyyy
D   Long Date   dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
Y   Month/Year  MMMM, yyyy
M   Month/Day   yyyy MMMM
```

Comment: What does (Resource1) and "BirthdayPrefixKey" and "BirthdayPostfixKey" represent in this context? sorry I dont understand

Comment: i have editted you can try this one and that are the things used for prefix and postfix

Comment: should i do this with or without displaydate thing i already have